# TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

I want to show a progress bar while the server is processing the formular data which was posted before. The client is able to check the progress on this url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/loader/progress. The following code works perfectly and the console shows the percentage for one time:

```
$.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/loader/progress', function(data){
    console.log(data)
});
```

Now I want to send a getJSON request to this address as long as the value is < 100%. How do I do this? The following code gives this error message:

Uncaught TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function

```
var updateProgress = function(){
    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/loader/progress', function(data)
    {
        if(data.percentageProcessed != 100) {
            document.getElementById('progressBar').value = data.percentageProcessed;
            setInterval(updateProgress, 2000);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('progressBar').value = 100;
        }
    });
}
updateProgress();
```

I load jQuery after the  opening of my HTML document with the following source: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

It's all the same with the following code. Here the error message says: TypeError: $.ajax is not a function:

```
var doAjax = function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/loader/progress',
        success: function(data){
            if (data.percentageProcessed != 100) {
                document.getElementById('progressBar').value = data.percentageProcessed;
                doAjax();
            } else {
                document.getElementById('progressBar').value = 100;
            }
        }
    });
}
doAjax();
```

Thank you for your help.

Edit: This is my jQuery import:

```
<body>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
...
</body>
```

Comment: Sounds like the `$` variable is either `undefined` or not what you think it is - so either jQuery hasn't been loaded, or has been overridden by another library which uses `$`. Try typing `$` into the console on your page, as well as `jQuery`, and seeing what you get. (If there's a conflict you will have to use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: can you try type $ in console and check ?

Comment: Hi Windschief and welcome to SO. Can you post how you are adding jQuery to your page?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I also tried with jQuery instead of $ and it does not work. As the first code snippet works I don't think that jQuery was not loaded. When I remove setInterval(updateProgress, 2000); from the second code snippet or remove doAjax(); from the third one everything works.

Comment: right click, view source, count the number of jquery.js you load. the number must be 1

Comment: You do not have jQuery included twice right?

Comment: Omg that was it. At the end of the page I had another import of jQuery for bootstrap. I feel dumb now :D Thank you very very much for your fast help!

Comment: That was the gist of my comment too :)

Answer (score 2):

The root cause was: there were two imports of jQuery on the same page. 
The Solution: remove one of the two jQuery imports.
[cleaning up]